# Send Enter key to Ansible expect responses

Tags: ansible

I'm using the expect module.

```
- name: "WAMUI Prerequisites Installer"
    expect:
    command: "./file.bin"
    responses:
            'PRESS \<ENTER\> TO CONTINUE:':'\n'
```

Would entering `'\n'` in the response send the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

Comment: Did you try? What was the result?

Comment: I did. But I ran into errors. troubleshooting them. Not sure if it's because of this or something else I goofed up.

Answer (score 12):

Any string you provide as a response in the `expect` module will be terminated by the `0x0a`. To simulate pressing just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> it's enough to define an empty string:

```
responses:
  'PRESS \<ENTER\> TO CONTINUE:': ''
```

> Would entering '\n' in the response send the enter key?

It will send the `n` character followed by `0x0a`.

<sup>You also need to fix indentation and spacing in the code you posted.</sup>